# R ggplot2 the names of the biggest values on x axis

Tags: r, plot, ggplot2

Hi there) can anybody help me. I have a big DF with two columns Country_dest and SumTotal (is value), trying to use `qplot` function

```
qplot(country_dest, SumTotal, data=Africa) 

Brunei       58
Aruba        73
Cuba         95
Nicaragua    97
Turkmenistan 99
Saint Lucia  102
Honduras    153
Barbados    161
Haiti   165
Montenegro  175
```

And I would like to draw a plot, but on x axis put the name of the countries (for example 7 or 6 of them) with the highest value of SumTotal, is it possible to do?)

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

using ggplot, just reorder by population:

```
ggplot(data = Africa, aes(x= reorder(country_dest, -SumTotal), y= SumTotal)) + geom_bar(stat = "identity")
```

if you just wanna take say the top 5 use arrange and then subset:

```
require(dplyr)
Africa.ordered <- arrange(Africa, -SumTotal)
Africa.top5 <- Africa.ordered[1:5,]
```

and then draw your plot

Comment: Thank you, grrgrrbla!!! second solution works fine, but first gives the same problem, it plots but gives an error - "position_stack requires constant width: output may be incorrect", and on x axis gives me all the countries and it is unreadable for an eye.  (( But I wanted to plot all data, and tried to put on x axis only the names of countries (top 5) with the highest value of SumTotal.

Comment: happy I could help, you can tick the button on the left to accept the answer then,

Comment: grrgrrbla, sorry for a disturbing, maybe you can show me how to plot all data but put on x axis only the names of countries (top 5) with the highest value of SumTotal